# How to reverse a bit shifting method

Tags: java, bit-shift

I have this method:

```
public static void dumpParameters(byte b) {
    System.out.println("Parameters: " + Integer.toHexString(b));
    System.out.println("Param 1: " + ((b & 0x01) >> 0));
    System.out.println("Param 2: " + ((b & 0x02) >> 1));
    System.out.println("Param 3: " + ((b & 0x0c) >> 2));
    System.out.println("Param 4: " + ((b & 0xf0) >> 4));
}
```

I tried to reverse it with this method:

```
public static byte setParameters(int b1, int b2, int b3, int b4) {
    byte result = (byte) b1;
    result |= (b2 | 0x02) << 1;
    result |= (b3 | 0x0c) << 2;
    result |= (b4 | 0xf0) << 4;
    return result;
}
```

Calling these methods like so:

```
dumpParameters((byte) 0xb2);
byte result = setParameters(0, 1, 0, 11);
dumpParameters(result);
```

Results:

```
Parameters: ffffffb2
Param 1: 0
Param 2: 1
Param 3: 0
Param 4: 11
Parameters: ffffffb6
Param 1: 0
Param 2: 1
Param 3: 1
Param 4: 11
```

The result I'm interested in ends up with a value of **ffffffb6**; I expected **ffffffb2**.

The setParameters method doesn't work, why?

Comment: I don't think you want to `or` against a constant. Try using `result |= b2 << 1;` etc.

Comment: How would dropping the 0x0c for instance work? The dump method is valid for my application, that much I'm certain of.

Comment: Because `result |= (b3 | 0x0c)` bitwise-ors `result` against `52` in this instance. From what I can tell you're only trying to set the 2 bits at position 5 and 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bitwise or will totally ruin the parameters, just shift them instead and then take the required bits:

```
public static byte setParameters(int b1, int b2, int b3, int b4) {
    byte result = (byte) b1;
    result |= (b2 << 1) & 0x02;
    result |= (b3 << 2) & 0x0c;
    result |= (b4 << 4) & 0xf0;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I *think* you're trying to get:

```
public static byte setParameters(int b1, int b2, int b3, int b4) {
    byte result = (byte) b1;
    result |= (b2 & 0x01) << 1;
    result |= (b3 & 0x03) << 2;
    result |= (b4 & 0x0f) << 4;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your method works as well, but @cy3er submitted one that "looks" closer to the original forward (dump) method.